# How do I easily condense a whole ruby program into one file?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I really like writing command line applications in ruby.  However, when working on lots of ruby projects I end up switching between different ruby versions with something like rvm, rbenv or chruby.  This means I need to install ruby command line utilities for every version of ruby I work on.  I've gotten used to this, but when distributing ruby command line apps to other devs they get confused when running whateverrubyapp that worked in one directory now doesn't work in another directory because the ruby version is different, or even worse they're using gemsets.

Is there an easy way to bundle up a ruby application with all it's dependencies including gems into a single file so that I can just have people put that file in their ~/bin dir so that it behaved somewhat as though it were a compiled application?

For example, I whipped up a little rake task to take a project with no gem dependencies and put it all into one file https://github.com/mmrobins/git-rank/blob/master/Rakefile.  However, I have much more complex command line apps that have gem dependencies I would want to include into a single file for easy distribution.

Comment: It seems like this is a good use for [Bundler](http://bundler.io). See "[Sharing Your Application With Other Developers](http://bundler.io/v1.6/rationale.html)". Set up a "Gemfile" file, and have the user run `bundle install` before they try to run the script the first time. When writing code, we're supposed to sniff for the features we need using methods like [`respond_to?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F), whether they're built into Ruby or a gem. Having to install multiple Rubyies makes me think you're not doing that part right.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I have command line tools that I want to use across many of our web apps, and these apps have different versions of ruby (1.8.7, 1.9.3, 2.1.2, etc).  Obviously it would be nice if they were all the same ruby version, but that's not something I have control over.  Bundler works great for installing the gems for these web apps, but for installing a command line tool as a gem it doesn't help.  I'll update the question with a specific example project.

Comment: Have you tried running them with different versions of Ruby? Ruby maintains a lot of consistency and compatibility between version upgrades, and it's trivial to either change the #! line with sed, or to launch a script using an explicit version of Ruby.